# 6TB HDD in Synology RS814 NAS

Tags: nas, home-server, synology, file-server, rack

Is it possible to put 6TB HDD's in a synology RS814 NAS? This isn't clear. This is the NAS:
https://www.synology.com/nl-nl/products/RS814

http://www.nascenter.be/product/385420/synology-rs814.html?_ga=1.241934466.1865044569.1410217003

Comment: Why does my question gets a downvote? (-1)

Comment: Because you could have found that out by checking the Synology documentation. As I did in about twenty seconds. Nevertheless, I felt your question deserved an answer for the benefit of anyone who might also search for this information.

Comment: Well I checked it out on several sites, but they have different information. Some say the maximum capacity is 16tb, this results in hdd's of 4tb. So I'm asking because I'm not sure and I want clarity on this.

Comment: Synology themselves say the [maximum raw capacity is 24TB](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products/RS814#spec). That will be with a current version of DSM; it is possible that earlier versions were limited to 16TB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Synology's disk drive compatibility](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/compatibility/hd/RS814) list, yes.

Bear in mind that during the time it takes to rebuild a RAID after replacing a failed disk, another disk can fail. This means that you need a backup which is as up-to-date as possible at all times. Also, disk drives can suffer from bit-rot: [Is bit rot on hard drives a real problem? What can be done about it?](https://serverfault.com/q/77710/109573) - Synology's DSM offers [data scrubbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scrubbing) to check for that.

Comment: So what you are saying: it's better to install 4 HDD's directly? Not place 1 HDD and after a month place a 2nd HDD?

Comment: when a disk is rebuilding, it can take time... a lot of time when you are using hdds > 4TB... and if you lose a second hdd during the rebuild you will lose everything. It could happen, but if you can use a hot spare if your can or a more robust raid type... it allows for extra protection.

Comment: What raid type is the safest to use then?

Comment: http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/_common/compatibility/_education/raid_level_compar_wp.htm

Comment: @Gilko [What is the fastest and safest RAID combination for SATA drives?](http://serverfault.com/q/121017/109573) Bear in mind that with the NAS you have, the RAID read/write speeds will probably be in excess of your LAN speed, so there is no need to worry about speeds when using RAID 5. You definitely want a RAID level which spreads data across disks. The default with a Synology NAS device when you have several disks installed will be enough. For 6TB disks, you really want to install four of them, and probably have a second NAS to back up to. DSM makes it easy to do that.

Comment: ... I have no connection to Synology other than using their products.

Comment: Maybe it's better to consider buying a 1 bay NAS, so I don't have to use RAID?